# Concurrency primitives in Racket

Tags: concurrency, racket, semaphore, countdownlatch

I'm learning how to implement semaphores and countdown latches in Racket.
Right now I'm using the Racket Docs, but I do not find them very useful.

Would you recommend any websites, tutorials, textbooks, videos that can assist me throughout this learning experience, while addressing deadlocks, race conditions, and other concurrency issues? Your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you learning to use them or implement them?

Comment: I'm learning how to implement them using channels and other concurrency constructs in Racket. It is very different for me since my background is c++/java.

Answer (score 1):

The Little Book of Semaphores is very nice:

http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/LittleBookOfSemaphores.pdf

It does not use Racket, but translating the examples would make a nice a learning experience.